# Как примерно реализован препроцессор типа Jade/Pug?

Tags: jade, pug

Если бы мне на данный момент сказали сделать препроцессор типа Jade/Pug, то я бы не придумал ничего, кроме как пропускать каждую строку через большое количество if-блоков, где в каждом условии анализируется, с чего начинается строка, далее валидация строки и так далее. Но так ли реализован препроцессор Jade/Pug? Я думаю, тот принцип, который я привёл, ужасный с точки зрения производительности.

Конечно, я не ожидаю увидеть продробную статью по этому поводу в ответе, но если Вы знаете хотя бы принцип работы Jade/Pug, то буду рад даже краткому объяснению.

Answer (score 0):

Откройте [официальный GitHub проекта](https://github.com/pugjs/pug) и посмотрите сами на исходный код. Навскидку, там предложенный вами вариант как раз используется.